# FTP-клиент создаёт, но не передаёт файл, ошибка 425 Unable to build data connection

Tags: ftp

Здравствуйте, есть `FTP`-сервер, со всех компьютеров которые я пробовал сервер файлы принимает, а с сервера на `Ubuntu`, после команды `put` создаёт пустой файл на `ftp`-сервере и после недолгого ожидания выводит ошибку

> 425 Unable to build data connection. Connection time out.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, причина в брандмауэре.

Решения два:

- Переключиться в пассивный режим передачи на клиенте;
- Или открыть порты на клиенте.

Если используется SSL, то, вероятно, надо кликнуть галочку ~"Разрешить повторное использование сессии".

Comment: 1. В пассивный режим переключался на клиенте - не помогает, я делаю всё из командной строки >quote pasv
2. по поводу открыть порт добавлял правила в iptables
iptables -I INPUT 7 -p tcp --sport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 7 -p tcp --sport 23 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Вот часть вывода OUTPUT по >iptables -L -n -v:
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1339 packets, 76997 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                            10G   12T ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Comment: Убедись в отсутствии NAT-a. Если он есть, на него надо навесить софтину для корректной работы с FTP.

И проверь на всякий, открыты ли порты 1024-65534, по которым собственно и гуляют данные.